# Unique solution to an integral equation? (Moment generating function)

Tags: integral-equations, moment-generating-functions

I have a solution to the following integral equation:

\begin{equation}
\gamma(t) = \dfrac{2}{t}\int_{0}^{1} \gamma(t x)(e^{(1-x)t}-1)dx, \, \gamma(0)=1.
\end{equation}

Can one show that the  solution is unique?  I am only in interested in positive, analytic, increasing solutions.  ($\gamma$ is a moment generating function for a  [0, 1]- valued random variable.)

I know nothing about integral equations.

Answer (score 2):

Figured out the answer:  Make the substitution (suggested by a colleague) $u = tx$.  If we differentiate the equation twice, we get a second-order linear differential equation.  I know $\gamma'(0) = 1/2$ (the expected value of the random variable), so the solution is indeed unique.